# If I can do a "require" inside a callback in node-mysql, do the module functions get added to the callback scope or to global scope?

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback, require, commonjs

I am using nodejs and the node-mysql driver.  I find myself doing repetitive boiler plate such as

client.query(querystr, queryparams, function callback(err, results, fields){

```
     if (err){ do err related stuff }
     else { do success related stuff }
```

}

Bottom-line most of the time everything is straightforward and repeated except what happens on success which varies wildly depending on the query and context.
So I'd like to encapsulate all this in a single function and pass in a querystr, queryparams and a success function.

Problem: I can't do this as this is inside a callback and I cant make the query engine use my success function even if I pass it in via the callback arguments.

So I am thinking can I do a "require" inside the callback and if so will the functions in the "required" module be added to the global scope or the callback scope?  I am hoping the latterB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign variables to module scope, which is an approximation of 'global' like this:

```
function a() { module.sys = require("sys"); }
function b(cb) { cb() };
b(a);
console.log(sys);
```

Comment: Remember that `require` is blocking and should not be used after the server has started (i.e. once your serving requests/responses). I also recommend using `module.sys` rather then `sys` as the lack of `var` is 99% of the time a bug rather then an intended piece of code

Comment: The question, and the answer, were about scope, not blocking or `module.sys` or mistakenly leaving out `var` :)

Comment: @nicolaskruchten the term "global" is also misleading because node has true global scope (on the `global` object) and module scope on the `module` object. using `a = 4` writes to module scope which is only accessible within a module. besides `a = 4` is invalid in ES5 strict mode. All in all it's both confusing and bad advice.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten thanks for fixing that up. You can access `sys` in the `module` state without calling `module.sys`. Just getting `sys` will look in the `module` object because it's in the scope chain just like `window` in the browser, except in node `global` is also in the scope chain one level above `module`.

Comment: @Raynos - thanks about the blocking part - because this is inside a callback - so it doesn't seem to make sense to do a require there - in fact it seems rather dumb now that I think about it.

Comment: @Nitin require isn't that bad if you've called it before. If you can _garantuee_ that you've called it before then it is cached. I personally think it's bad style and avoid it, mainly because a maintenance programmer has to double check it's _always_ cached.